# what does ""value" parameter is not used" on the setter mean please?

Tags: c#, properties, resharper

For the below codes, the reason I add "private set" without a body is to make it immutable outside of this class. The resharper keep telling me ""value" parameter is not used"", what does this means please?

```
    public string ErrorCode
    {
        get
        {
            if (!this.request.Completed)
            {
                return "Incomplete";
            }
            return this.request.Error.ToString();
        }

        private set
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: First google result: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/'value'+parameter+is+not+used

Comment: There is an implicit `value` parameter for the set method, and you are doing nothing with it. The fact that the set method is private makes it immutable outside of the class, the fact that it has no body means that it is actually immutable from inside the class too (since you don't use the value that gets passed in). You should either not have a set method at all, or you should use the value to actually update your object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going to use a setter then you need to also make use of the `value` keyword. If you dont want a setter, making the `ErrorCode` property readonly then you could just remove the `private-set` clause. There is no way to avoid this otherwise.

```
 public string ErrorCode
    {
        get
        {
            if (!this.request.Completed)
            {
                return "Incomplete";
            }
            return this.request.Error.ToString();
        }

        private set
        {
             _globalVar = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thx. So basically I need to add a globe variable.

Comment: @Sam003 Correct. If you're going to write a more complex property then it needs to modify another variable. Might be better to use a public method for your case though.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have an automatic like setter if you've implemented get. You have few options:

1.Remove the setter all together, so you will have get only property. You can manipulate private field from class level directly. Not recommended

2. Provide minimal implementation in setter:   _yourPrivateField = value;
   Lazy but will do.
3. Provide setter with some validation-always preferred.